# alias in .bashrc using Mac OSX: command works on the command line but in an alias it doesn't work

Tags: bash, command, alias

I realise there are a few questions similar to this but nothing that fully addresses the issue I'm getting.

I'm writing a few alias' for terminal commands I often use.

`$ cd ~/Documents/blah/blah/blah`

This works as a terminal command, but when I try to turn this into an alias:

`alias pie='cd ~/Documents/blah/blah/blah'`

This doesn't work, `-bash: cd: Documents/blah/blah/blah: No such file or directory`

I'm storing the alias in .bashrc in my home directory. I'm using Mac OSX.

Anyone know why it would work as a straight command but not an alias?

Similarly, I use a vagrant machine, and I'd like the chain together two commands: one to ssh to vagrant and the other to open the shell:

`alias vshell='vagrant ssh && python manage.py shell`

But this doesn't seem possible, it only ever executes the first command, maybe because this takes a little longer to complete?

Thanks

Comment: What do you get when you do `alias pie` ? and `ls -l ~/Documents/blah/blah/blah` ?

Comment: You don't run `vagrant ssh`, *then* `python`; `python` is the command that `ssh` should run on the remote shell, so something like `alias vshell='vagrant ssh python manage.py shell'`.